# Model's end not following bone

Tags: modeling, bones

I'm just so new to blender I can't even figure out why this is happening. (picture)
[image]

Comment: that part of the mesh is surely missing weights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a weighting issue. This should fix it:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode.
- Select one set of the problem vertices (making the armature modifier work in edit mode will be useful here).
- Go to the mesh properties tab of the Properties panel (the triangle), and find the vertex group matching their bone. Hit Assign.
- Repeat with the other arm.